# jQuery halt execution until an event is dispatched

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Ok, so I trying to achieve a console-like behavior and I need to pause the execution until some event is dispatched, what I exactly need is this:

```
var evt = $("element").waitForKeyDown();
```

This hypothetical function should pause the execution until the user presses a key on the "element" element, which is supossed to be a textfield. Then when the user presses any key on that textfield, the execution should continue and evt should contain the information related to that event.

Is this possible to achieve in javascript? or a close behavior that works like.

Answer (score 6):

You don't ever want to wait in JavaScript--there's only one thread, and you need it available to handle other events that may be coming in to other parts of the page.

What you want to do instead is take everything that's supposed to happen after the point where you want to wait and package it up into a `function(){}`. (This function is called a "continuation" and you'll encounter this pattern all over the place in JavaScript and other heavily asynchronous environments.)

From there, you'll register your new function using the following jQuery:

```
var evt = $("element").keydown(function(event){
   var keypressed = event.keyCode;

   // do whatever you'd like with the keypress.
});
```

You could consider using [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) instead of keydown, but keypress (almost paradoxically) doesn't get you all keypresses, just those that turn into text input of some sort.

Comment: The thing is that I need to block the execution, because the behavior I want to achieve here is the same that alert, confirm and prompt have. I need to wait until the user inputs some data.

Comment: @Andrés when you say "block execution", I assume you mean blocking the web page for all user interaction until the correct keypress event has dispatched, am I right?

Comment: When I mean block, I mean the same effect that alert, prompt and confirm have. I would like to stop my script at some point time and then when the user presses the return key on a textfield, do some stuff with the content of that textfield

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there are no blocking actions in javascript, except alert and prompt. The only way to do this is (could be wrong though):

```
var evt = $("element").on("click",function(){
  //Continue here
});
```

Comment: The thing is that I need to block the execution, because the behavior I want to achieve here is the same that alert, confirm and prompt have. I need to wait until the user inputs some data

Comment: Why not just process the data in an anonymous function instead? For example - http://jsfiddle.net/zYej4/

Answer (score 0):

just use the keydown event. it does exactly what you want to achieve: do an action only when a key has been pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery .keyDown http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

```
var evt = $("element").keyDown(function(){
  //Rest of your code
});
```